# For which p the series converge?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n!}\right)^{p}$$

Please verify answer below

Answer (score 2):

Comparison test

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}\right)^{p}=\frac{1}{(n+1)^{p}}=\begin{cases}
1 & \Leftrightarrow p=0\\
0 & \Leftrightarrow p\neq0
\end{cases}$$

The series have the same convergence as $\frac{1}{n}$, so for:

1. $p>1$ converge
2. for $p<1$ don't converge

Comment: I think you mean, converge for $p>0$.

Comment: What if $p < 0$?

Comment: @rlgordonma yes, I've edited.

Comment: @Thomas - I've forgotten this. Let me think

Comment: @Joggi: You might still want to edit some more. Do you mean: "For $p>0$ series converges" and "For $p\leq 0$ the series doesn't converge, ..." ?

Comment: Here was a mistake. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: @Joggi: I still do not think this answer is correct.  For the ratio test, convergence is according to whether the ratio is > or < 1.  Think about the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

The series diverges for $p\le0$, since the terms do not approach $0$.  For $p>0$, the $n$-th root of the $n$-th term is
$$
(n!)^{-p/n} = e^{-p(\log n + O(1))} \sim Cn^{-p},
$$
which approaches zero.  Therefore it converges by the root test for all $p>0$.